# How to get list of all files containing one pattern and not containing another one?

Tags: bash, grep

I am looking for one CLI that would return me a list of files that contain `foo` text and that do not contain `bar` inside.

Please note that I am looking for a portable solution, so keep in mind the differences between GNU and non-GNU versions of awk/grep/...

If it can be don in a single command, even better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `find + awk` solution:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec \
awk '/foo/{m=1} /bar/{n=1} END{if (m && !n) print FILENAME}' {} \;
```

Comment: Might `/bar/{nextfile}` be more efficient, since it would potentially discount unacceptable files sooner? Also, do you need to reset `m` and `n` to `0` at the end of each file?

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes for `nextfile` but that would make it gawk-only and the OP did ask for a portable solution so he should use `exit` instead of `nextfile` and do it after setting `n` (`/bar/{n=1;exit}`) since the `END` section will still be executed. No for resetting the variables since awk will be called one file at a time and they'll be reset to zero-or-null every time awk is called.

Answer (score 1):

This will stop grep on the first match, but does involve reading the same file twice.

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'if grep -q -m1 foo $0 && ! grep -q -m1 bar $0; then echo $0; fi' {} \;
```

Comment: You're correct, that version wasn't working. I've changed my answer to still use grep, but working I believe.

Comment: Interesting to note with this one, the lazy evaluation of the and's can be used instead of an if: `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'test*' -exec bash -c 'grep -q -m1 foo $0 && ! grep -q -m1 bar $0 && echo $0' {} \;`